# Zsh Costumizing

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I was colorizing my prompt. I did it in .zshrc file
.zshrc

```
  PROMPT=$'%B%{\e[38;2;224;108;117m('                                                                                                                                 
  PROMPT+=$'%{\e[38;2;229;192;123m%n'                                                                                                                                 
  PROMPT+=$'%{\e[38;2;97;175;239m%(#..@)'                                                                                                                           
  PROMPT+=$'%{\e[38;2;152;195;121m%m'                                                                                                                                 
  PROMPT+=$'%{\e[38;2;224;108;117m)-['                                                                                                                                
  PROMPT+=$'%{\e[38;2;198;120;221m%~'                                                                                                                                 
  PROMPT+=$'%{\e[38;2;224;108;117m]'                                                                                                                                  
  PROMPT+=$'%{\e[38;2;224;108;117m$:'                                                                                                                                 
  PROMPT+=$'%b%{$reset_color'
```

and i am getting colors i want but if i enter a long command like
**cd Desktop**
i am getting this:

```
cd Desktopkali)-[~]$:cd
```

this is that i want:

```
(enes-can@kali)-[~]$:cd Desktop
```

How can i fix this.

Comment: Use Grammarly to avoid your very basic spelling mistakes.

Comment: @Only0Night : If I count correctly, you have in your prompt string 10 opening `%{` and not a single closing `%}`. Or are all the missing ones provided by `$reset_color`?

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating this; you appear not to be closing any of the `%{`  to properly mark an ANSI escape sequence as a zero-width item for purposes of calculating the prompt length and cursor position, but you don't need raw ANSI escape sequences in the first place.

This does require you to represent your RGB triplets in hexadecimal first, though.

```
PROMPT='%B%F{#e06c75}('   # 224 == 0xe0, 108 == 0x6c, 117 == 0x75
PROMPT+='%F{...}%n'                                                                                                                                 
PROMPT+='%F{...}%(#..@)'                                                                                                                           
PROMPT+='%F{...}%m'                                                                                                                                 
PROMPT+='%F{...})-['                                                                                                                                
PROMPT+='%F{...}%~'                                                                                                                                 
PROMPT+='%F{...}]'                                                                                                                                  
PROMPT+='%F{...}$:'                                                                                                                                 
PROMPT+='%b%f'
```

The benefit of using `%F` is that `zsh` already knows that the byte sequence it produces should not contribute to the prompt length, relieving you of the burden of using `%{ ... %}` everywhere.